# Is this a proper way to check a viewstate of type int?

Tags: c#, casting

In page load I'm saving a query string int value in a viewstate. Then I save it to my DB. Here is the code I use to retrieve viewstate value and validating it:

```
protected int CurrentCom
{
    get 
    {
        if (ViewState["CurrentCom"] == null)
            return 0;
        else
        {
            int temp;
            if (int.TryParse(ViewState["CurrentCom"].ToString(), out temp))
                return temp;
            else return 0;
        }

    }
    set { ViewState["CurrentCom"] = value; }
}
```

Is there a better way to make this shorter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do like this:

```
return (int)(ViewState["CurrentCom"] ?? 0);
```

Comment: cool ! where was this all this time ? thank you Mattias

Comment: I would usually do `return ViewState["CurrentCom"] as int? ?? 0`, but this feels much better. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with C#, but the else branch looks unnecessary, since if `ViewState["CurrentCom"] == null` is `true` the method returns with `0`.

```
if (ViewState["CurrentCom"] == null) {
    return 0;
}
int currentCom;
if (int.TryParse(ViewState["CurrentCom"].ToString(), out currentCom)) {
    return currentCom;
}
return 0;
```